# Rails Console still running after Control-Z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

After I close rails console with Control-Z, I'm given the output of terminal, but Rails Console is still running. Pressing up gives me a "[" and pressing enter gives me a new line in Rails console. I'm running a Macbook Pro with OSX. Are there any recommendations on how to fix this? [Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY1OM.png)

Comment: This is a bug. Control-Z sends SIGTSTP, which should be caught to allow readline to restore terminal settings before going to sleep. readline normally does this, but not in rails console. Instead, it catches SIGTSTP and ignores it (and continues reading input) which is the bug. I will investigate and fix it soon, because it annoys me enormously.

Comment: I've had this bug for a long time too. I thought maybe it was related to tmux, which I'm running console in. It somehow splits the output, so characters I type will alternately be sent to the shell command-line and the Rails console. So it's not possible to actually do anything sensible in either of them and I have to kill the console process from another window or destroy the tmux pane.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctrl+c` or `exit`.

If that doesn't work try:

`ps aux | grep ruby`

`kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Z doesn't exit command-line programs; it temporarily stops them and returns you to the shell.

As JamesDullaghan said, you probably want Ctrl-C (to exit nearly any command-line program) or `exit` (specific to IRB).